# Why does 'outer inline' template does not compile?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Ok, so here is a code :

```
#include <sstream>

struct A {
    class Type {};
    template < typename Type >
    Type as( void ) {
        std::istringstream test;

        Type temp;
        test >> temp;

        return temp;
    }
};
```

It compiles fine, no problem at all.

Now, here is *almost* the same code :

```
#include <sstream>

struct A {
    class Type {};
    template < typename Type >
    inline Type as(void);
};

template < typename Type >
Type A::as( void ) {
    std::istringstream test;

    Type temp;
    test >> temp;

    return temp;
}
```

Boom, it doesn't compile anymore. Error :

```
t.cc:14:10: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istringstream' (aka 'basic_istringstream<char>') and 'A::Type')
    test >> temp;
    ~~~~ ^  ~~~~
```

I have reproduced this behavior with clang and gcc.

Why are the compilers using the wrong type in the second case ? (just to be clear : I know that there is a conflict with the enumeration, but from my understanding, the first code should also fail to compile if it was the real problem)

Comment: Fwiw, similar behavior on Apple LLVM 4.1 in both stdc++11 and gcc++11 modes.

Comment: i have downvoted this. please fix the code snippet so that they dont contain those copy paste bugs anymore and I will retract the vote.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Are you talking about the extra qualification warning ? I've removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope in A::as() uses A::Type as the type qualifier for temp. The easiest way to see this is to change to nested class name to something besides Type.

The better question is *why* it happens in the first place. It is related to point-of-declaration, name look-up, and name-hiding, all covered in sections 3.3, 3.4 and 14.6.4 of the standard. It is a pretty meaty set of sections and I'll post the specific clauses as they relate to this issue if/when i get the time to narrow them down. So far I'm leaning on 3.3.9-10 and 3.4

Anyway changing the class name allows the template argument to resolve once out of the scope of the struct *declaration*, the latter being key to why it happens in the first place (so I'm lead to believe by the standard, anyway).

```
struct A
{
    class TypeX {};
    template < typename Type >
    Type as(void);
};

template < typename Type >
inline Type A::as( void )
{
    std::istringstream test;
    Type temp;
    test >> temp;
    return temp;
}
```

I am *very* confident if I have the wrong sections of the standard relating to this issue there are *ample* occupants of StackOverflow that will send hot-rods through this answer.